# Is it faster to create a new Map or clear it and use again?

Tags: scala, performance

I need to use many Maps in my project so I wonder which way is more efficient:

```
val map = mutable.Map[Int, Int] = mutable.Map.empty
for (_ <- 0 until big_number)
  {
    // do something with map
    map.clear()
  }
```

or

```
for (_ <- 0 until big_number)
  {
    val map = mutable.Map[Int, Int] = mutable.Map.empty
    // do something with map
  }
```

to use in terms of time and memory?

Comment: If you ask any Scala developer, they will tell you to not use a mutable map at all.

Comment: Depends on use case, but your examples don't show anything suggesting that mutability would be of any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my formal answer would always be depends. As you need to benchmark your own scenario, and see what fits better for your scenario. I'll provide an example how you can try benchmarking your own code. Let's start with writing a measuring method:

```
def measure(name: String, f: () => Unit): Unit = {
  val l = System.currentTimeMillis()
  println(name + ": " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - l))
  f()
  println(name + ": " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - l))
}
```

Let's assume that in each iteration we need to insert into the map one key-value pair, and then to print it:

```
Await.result(Future.sequence(Seq(Future {
  measure("inner", () => {
    for (i <- 0 until 10) {
      val map2 = mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]
      map2(i) = i
      println(map2)
    }
  })
},
Future {
  measure("outer", () => {
    val map1 = mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int]
    for (i <- 0 until 10) {
      map1(i) = i
      println(map1)
      map1.clear()
    }
  })
})), 10.seconds)
```

The output in this case, is almost always equal between the `inner` and the `outer`. Please note that in this case I run the two options in parallel, as if I wouldn't the first one always takes significantly more time, no matter which one of then is first.

Therefore, we can conclude, that in this case they are almost the same.

But, if for example I add an immutable option:

```
Future {
  measure("immutable", () => {
    for (i <- 0 until 10) {
      val map1 = Map[Int, Int](i -> i)
      println(map1)
    }
  })
}
```

it always ends up first. This makes sense because immutable collections are much more performant than the mutables.

For better performance tests you probably need to use some third parties, such as [scalameter](https://scalameter.github.io/), or others that exists.